# Not getting boot loader screen to choose between Ubuntu and Windows 7

Tags: grub2, boot-repair

I was using 12.04 beta. I was asked by update manager to make required updates, which I did. I shut down my PC that night and the next day I was not able to boot into the graphical interface. After some attempts to fix it, I decided to remove beta and do a fresh install of Ubuntu 12.04.

I went into Windows 7, and in the disk management tool I deleted the Linux volume and swap volume. Then when I rebooted I was stuck with a grub rescue screen. I was not able to boot into Windows 7. I used [boot-repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair). I clicked on <kbd>recommended repair</kbd> and voila!! I got my Windows 7 back. So I decided to install Ubuntu 12.04 again. I did and when I rebooted I was not asked for OS options and was directly taken to Windows 7. I tried using [this help wiki page](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2#Reinstalling_GRUB2) to reinstall GRUB, but I am still not able to go into Ubuntu or get a boot loader screen. I guess my GRUB was messed up pretty badly when I deleted the Linux partition in the first place.

What should I do now?

Comment: Have you tried running boot repair again since you reinstalled Ubuntu?

Comment: yes. This bootinfosummary is post reinstall of ubuntu. which I have tried an hour ago.

Comment: So while reinstalling grub2 when it comes to package configuration and asks where to place grub2. I should select sda instead of sdc. Is that what you are trying to tell me? @aking1012

Comment: Ok I will give it a try and come back to you.

Comment: I just did update-grub and grub-install /dev/sda and rebooted. Amazingly it worked. Thanks @aking1012

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Moving comments to an answer:

Grub2 is installed to sdc not sda. if you want it to magically find, it needs to be on the drive your motherboard defaults to. This in most cases is sda.

Under typical circumstances when installing grub2 it should be on `/dev/sda`.

You can do this from a liveCD or using the boot repair disks you found.  I tend to favor a liveCD because I control exactly what is going on, but it lacks an `easy-button`.

Answer (score 0):

Looking at bootinfo grab
 => Grub2 (v1.99) is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdc and looks at sector 1 of 
    the same hard drive for core.img. core.img is at t his location and looks 
    for (,msdos5)/boot/grub on this drive.

so now you are having a windows loader in MBR of your primary hdd(sda) ;perhaps u can try making sdc as your primary disk and try a boot (settings to be done in BIOS).If your ubuntu install is proper u will get in to this only.But for dual boot u need to chainload one or other

option1: u can use the windows loader to chainload grub using 3rd party softwares http://www.supergrubdisk.org/wiki/Howto_Boot_Grub_from_windows (Windows Vista (with easybcd help)

option2:re-install grub to MBR of sda and do an os-probe to chainload windows7

Have your rescue-disks handy!!